# increasing the size of my /tmp folder

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

How do I increase the size of my /tmp folder? Jenkins gives me a "disk space is too low error" for the /tmp directory on my slave nodes

Here's what I've done to increase the partition size:

Run the following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/tmp-dir bs=1024M count=2
mke2fs -j /usr/tmp-dir
mount -t ext3 -o loop /usr/tmp-dir /tmp
```

added the line to my /etc/fstab file

```
/usr/tmp-dir /tmp ext3 defaults,loop 0 0
```

then

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
chown root.root /tmp
```

am I on the right track?

Comment: Don't do this. Instead, tell jenkins to store temporary files elsewhere.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: You go read the documentation, or do a Google search...

Answer (score 3):

in /etc/fstab you should see a line for `tmpfs`  with a `size=` parameter.  Change the number after the `=` to a suitable size

Comment: what command do you run after changing the /etc/fstab to have it take effect

Comment: got it I rebooted the server, but is there another command I can use?

Comment: @jasmine You can use "umount /tmp" to unmount the tmp directory then "mount -a" to mount everything as directed in your /etc/fstab file. This will avoid the reboot.

Comment: Of course this will be tricky when it comes to temp.  Many processes will have open files there.

Comment: Just run `mount -o remount /tmp` to make the new `size` parameter take effect.